# DMP MPU 6050 using STM32F4

Tags: accelerometer, gyroscope, dmp

I am trying to combine both data (accelerometer and gyroscope) from my MPU 6050 to get pitch, roll, and yaw value. I've able to get the accelerometer and gyroscope data, but I had problems combining it. I use Keil uVison as my IDE. Has anyone ever made the library to get that value using DMP on Keil?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is are a few Arduino libraries that do this. You can just translate the code to the stm32F4. The hardest part to find is the datasheet for the DMP